# AMQ Message move from one server to another us failing with a-1.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Tags: java, activemq-classic, messaging, mq

We are using A tool to move messages between two AMQ server and it is failing to connect to Server1 from server2, We are running command (`sudo /opt/amqScriptData/a -b ssl://Server1_IP:61616 -X /opt/amqScriptData/test.dlq1_0.json test.dlq1 -w 60000`) from server2. This was working fine with older version of Jar i.e 1.4.8. Only with updated jar [a-1.6.0-jar](https://github.com/fmtn/a/releases/download/v1.6.0/a-1.6.0-dist.tar.gz) we are seeing the issue:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: ssl://IP:61616. Reason: java.net.SocketException: Connection or outbound has closed
[2024-03-14T08:20:20.918Z]  at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:38)
[2024-03-14T08:20:20.918Z]  at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:374)
[2024-03-14T08:20:20.918Z]  at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:304)
[2024-03-14T08:20:20.918Z]  at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:244)
 Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection or outbound has closed
[2024-03-14T08:20:20.918Z]  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:1302)
[2024-03-14T08:20:20.918Z]  at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpBufferedOutputStream.flush(TcpBufferedOutputStream.java:115)
[2024-03-14T08:20:20.918Z]  at java.base/java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)
```

We tried `hostname` and `hostname -f` instead of IP in the move command and gets same error.

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ Classic are you attempting to connect to?